# jquery prompt before leaving site

Tags: jquery, prompt

With javascript or jQuery, how can I prompt a user with 'OK' and 'Cancel' before they leave a site outside the same domain? E.g., if someone is on the site https://www.mywebsite.com and wants to click a link/page other than https://www.mywebsite.com, the user should be prompted to confirm before leaving the site. It does not matter if the user jumps between pages within the same site, but the user needs to be prompted before leaving the site.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're required to show some code. Also, this question has been asked and answered many times. Please search.

Comment: Look at the `beforeunload` event.

Comment: To do what you describe you would need to hook an event handler to every element which can cause the user to be redirected (eg. `a` or `form` elements) and check the URL the user will be sent to. If it matches one of the domains in your list, show a modal before allowing them to continue. Note that using `onbeforeunload` is the usual way to achieve a redirect warning, but won't work in this case as you won't know the new URL in that event handler.